# CAML query format filter in DateTime column

Tags: caml-query, csom, date-time

I need to get the list item created on a particular **date**. The below caml query doesn't seem to work. It always retuns 0

```
 query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='false'>"+ date +"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></view>";
```

is there anything wrong in the query?

Comment: provide the 'date' return type used in query

Comment: Hi @DikeshGandhi the date is 4/18/2016 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I added the answer with SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime . If you need more info, please past your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to format the date like this:

**Server Site**

```
string date = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(inputDate);
```

Sample for your case:

```
inputDate = new DateTime(2016,04,18);
string date =  SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(inputDate);
```

**Client Side (client object model)**

```
string date = inputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

Comment: Thanks @jpussacq . I'm not sure if this will work on CSOM. but the below worked
 `query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'  IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' >"+date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></view>";`
Looks like the sputility method too does the same

Comment: Yes sorry. I had not realized it was CSOM

Comment: Updated my answer!